# set style only to the option of select

Tags: html, css

I have a select ond it's options contains text in hebrew and english. For example:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">(J9J) AMCKDPR ללא הגבלה IAPPLE</option>
    <option value="2">(B0A) MICROSOFT-עם הגבלה</option>
</select>
```

Because my pages are in hebrew, I am using direction:rtl to the page. As result I get the options displayd incorrect, something like:

```
IDIGITAL ללא הגבלה R9K) MICROUSIM)
```

If I change the direction of the whole select to ltr, I get the arrow of the select on the right - which is not good.

Is there any way I can set style only to the options of the select?

I am using IE8 and not firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done in CSS, since there is no element to set a rule on—you want *part* of the `option` element contents to be treated left-to-right, but you cannot use markup for that part. No markup is allowed inside the `option` element.

Therefore, the issue needs to be dealt with at the character level, using LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK and RIGHT-TO-LEFT mark, e.g.

```
<option value="1">&lrm;(J9J) AMCKDPR &rlm;ללא הגבלה IAPPLE</option>
```

I’m not sure how to apply the idea to the second `option` element; maybe just this way:

```
<option value="2">&lrm;(B0A) MICROSOFT-עם הגבלה</option>
```

but I cannot judge whether the result looks OK, because I can’t really read Hebrew.

Check out [Authoring HTML: Handling Right-to-left Scripts](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/).

Comment: This sounds promising, but when I add &lrm; in my asp.net page, the drop down get the text &lrm; instead of the mark I intend. Have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: ASP.NET does something to the ampersand—once you get `&lrm;` delivered to a browser, it will be recognized as standing for the control character (U+200E). I suppose it depends on the context how you need to escape the `&` character so that ASP.NET will just pass it thru and not interpret it as an operator.